# How can you keep the current line centered vertically in the editor

Tags: rider

I've searched all the settings and Google but can find nothing. It seems such an obvious feature. If I use the arrow keys to scroll vertically through the code, I quickly end up with the cursor at the top or bottom of the screen whereas I really want to be doing my editing near the centre of the screen, which means I have to do two operations: scroll the code to where I want it and then move the cursor.

What I want is to hit a shortcut (e.g. the Scroll Lock key) and then when I press up- or down-arrow the cursor stays where it is (relative to the screen) and the code scrolls past it.

I've read that some tools allow you to set the number of "always visible" lines above and below the cursor which would do the job, but I can't find that in Rider either.

Am I missing something obvious, or is there an add-in or something I can customize to get what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! There are `Move Up and Scroll` and `Move Down and Scroll` actions in the keymap settings. Assign hotkeys to them (weren't assigned in my config) and it will work like you described it.

Comment: Woo-hoo! Thanks Andrey.